# Rails - including module containing a class gives Uninitialized Constant error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module, mixins

My application has `lib/project/errors` which contains a bunch of Exception classes, one of which is ServiceException

```
module Project
  module Errors
    class ServiceException < Exception

      def initialize(message = nil)
        super message
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I am trying to use this in my GameService:

```
module GameMan


  class GameService
     Blah blah

     def validate(score)
       raise Project::Errors::ServiceException.new('blah')
     end

  end
end
```

This works, 
however I hate writing the full module path everywhere. Is there a way to avoid this?

I have tried

```
module GameMan

   class GameService
      include Project::Errors
      Blah blah

      def validate(score)
       raise ServiceException.new('blah')
      end

    end
end
```

This gives 
`uninitialized constant ServiceException` error.

I have 
`config.autoload_paths += 
%W(#{config.root}/lib #{config.root}/app/services)`
`already set in`application.rb``

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It is all about constants lookup.

`ServiceException` is defined in the scope of `Project::Errors`. When you reference `ServiceException` without prefixing `Project::Errors` it looks for the class defined in the outer scope, and failing, because there is none.

You should be using the full path.

Answer (score 0):

```
include Project::Errors
```

Replace above line to following line
    include Project::Errors::ServiceException